# JS Vanilla Валидация input:tel + автозаполнение +7 (...)

Tags: javascript, валидация

Вопрос: input с типом tel, хочу получить от него следующее поведение: юзер клацает на инпут, поле попадает в фокус и сразу заполняется "+7(", далее юзер вводит 3 цифры, скобка автоматически закрывается, ну и далее уже цифры в стандартизированном варианте через дефис. Итого маска: +7(111)111-11-11

Честно говоря, не могу придумать, как реализовать данную таску на чистом JS. Был бы благодарен за совет.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/tel

Comment: Здравствуйте
Честно говоря, не понимаю, чем поможет статья MDN, если вы имели в виду атрибут pattern у тэга, он не имеет функционала сделать "автокомплит" скобок и дэшей.